# How to merge two nsmutablearray together (Swift)

Tags: swift, nsarray

How to merge two nsmutablearray together or how to merge nsmutablearray to a NSArray?

i tried to merge two array with "+" but it fails. please help. thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't be working with `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` in Swift – use the native Swift collection types instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge 2 `NSMutableArrays` like this

```
var array1:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: [1,2,3])
var array2:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: [2,3,4])

var mergedArray = array1.arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray(array2 as [AnyObject])
```

Comment: i want to use the function objectAtIndex. however if it declare as any object, it doesn't support mergedArray.objectAtIndex()